# Filter a dictionary inside a tuple inside a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Is it possible to filter a dictionary, which is inside a tuple, which is inside a list based on it's keys in some list?

I have a list, each element in the list is a tuple, and the first element of each tuple is a dictionary. I want to only keep dictionary items whose keys are in some list.

How would I do this?

`mifw_basemodel = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', ...,'wordn']`

```
train_set = [({'Blah': 1, 'blah2': 18, ...}, 'pos'),
             ({'worrrda':22, 'hmmmsa':12,  ...}, 'neg'),
             ({'duhduh':21, 'blahduh':12,  ...}, 'pos'),
               ...
             ({'foo':2, 'bar':4,  ...}, 'pos')]
```

This is what I am trying at the moment: `{ your_key: train_set[0][0][your_key] for your_key in train_set[0][0] if train_set[0][0].keys() in mifw_basemodel}`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - I have added my attempt. Please remove downvote.

Comment: A [mre] needs to include what `train_set` and `mifw_basemodel` look like. It's a lot easier to figure out what you mean when you give a good example.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - is this suitable sir?

Answer (score 1):

you iterate the initial list by its contents, and then for each content of the list, iterate through the dictionary using this syntax:

```
for key, value in content.items()
    if key in mifw_basemodel:
        new_list.append(value)
```

this examines the dictionary as a whole instead of trying to find each items keys

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @MasenCodes I tried `[tupl for tupls in train_set for key,value in content.items() if key in mifw_basemodel then tupl.append(value)]` but this is not working

Comment: The easiest thing to do is create a new list from your existing one, adding only the desired values onto the new list. On earlier versions of Python, you were able to directly modify the size of a data structure while iterating through it, but with the current version it will throw an error